# Is Ajax as secure as an HTTP request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web

Basically I was wondering if AJAX is as secure as HTTP request, If there were any flaws in it I wasn't aware if, say i want to make a small change to a portion of the site, I would either refresh and re-render, or run an AJAX, but is AJAX as safe?

Let me edit to clarify, when i said an HTTP request, I meant by telling the browser to request the page from the server.

And instead of HTTP request, I suppose I should say HTTPS request.

So, is an ajax request made over the HTTPS protocol as secure as a regular visit to a website made by telling the browser to go to a site, over the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: AJAX fundamentally *IS* an HTTP request, so I'm unable to understand the premise of the quesiton...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because AJAX is a HTTP request.

Unfortunately, this is not secure either.

The golden rule is to use HTTPS! Ideally with TLS support.

Comment: The difference, if any, is that a normal HTTP call is generally generated by  the user interacting with the browser, where as an 'AJAX' call is initiated by the JavaScript engine. However, both use HTTP(S) to GET or POST the required data.

Comment: Yeah that is what I originally meant, I clarified it in an edit, Apologies for the confusion.